# How can I inherit a StatefulWidget's State?

Tags: flutter

Say I have a `GenericListItem` which is a `StatefulWidget` and calls

```
@override
GenericListItemState createState() => new GenericListItemState();
```

and say that `GenericListItemState` (created as `class GenericListItemState extends State<GenericListItem>`) contains the build method and all the real logic for manipulating `GenericListItems`.

If I want to create a `SpecificListItem` class which is just like a `GenericListItem` except it handles a couple methods differently, how do I go about this?  I can create a `SpecificListItem` which extends `GenericListItem` and overrides its `createState()` method but how do I extend the `GenericListItemState` that has all the important logic, including the methods I need to override? Aren't I required to create my `SpecificListItemState` so it extends `State<SpecificListItem>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it does work if I just do `SpecificListItemState extends GenericListItemState`.  Problem solved.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept your answer, so you get the points :) I think it's a day or two delay, but you can accept your answer soon.